# What is correct way to post yearly recurrence event in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I tried to post recurring event yearly using Microsoft graph API, with this simple payload I want to post event that repeats yearly on Tuesday the 3rd week of August,

I post it like this:

```
async function simplePost(){
  event = {
    body: {
      content: "<p>Post from console</p>",
      contentType: "html"
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: "2021-08-17",
      timeZone: "Asia/Bangkok"
    },
    recurrence: {
      pattern: {
        daysOfWeek: ["Tuesday"],
        interval: 1,
        month: 8,
        type: "relativeYearly"
      },
      range:{
        endDate: "2025-08-17",
        startDate: "2021-08-17",
        type: "endDate",
      }
    },
    start:{
      dateTime: "2021-08-17",
      timeZone: "Asia/Bangkok"
    },
    subject: "No title - testing"
  }

  try {
    console.log(event)
   post =  await graphClient
      .api('/me/events')
      .post(event);
  
   console.log(post)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

}
```

This event was posted posted successfully, however, the start date was wrong from payload that I posted; the start date of event became `2022-08-02T00:00:00.0000000`, but start date data I posted was `"2021-08-17"`. I wondered why it is wrong like this; and I want it to post correctly as my payload data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your payload, you are creating an event that: **Occurs every year on the first Tuesday of August effective Mon 8/1/2022 until Sat 8/16/2025**. You can see more on [recurrencePattern resource type Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/recurrencepattern?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) and

To start with, I suggest you specify the timestamp of the event because your start date is same as the end date. For example have *2021-08-17T12:00:00* to *2021-08-17T13:00:00* for an one hour event instead of *2021-08-17 to 2021-08-17*.

That said, the endpoint returns the next event in your series which in your case is *2022-08-02T00:00:00.0000000* and is expected as 2nd August 2021 is in the past.

Here is a version of your payload that can give you the desired result. Not that the stand and end dates will dictate how long your event is.

```
{
"subject": "Reapetes Yearly",
"body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Repeating Eevent"
},
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2021-08-17T12:00:00",
    "timeZone": "Asia/Bangkok"
},
"end": {
    "dateTime": "2021-08-17T13:00:00",
    "timeZone": "Asia/Bangkok"
},
"recurrence": {
    "pattern": {
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Tuesday"
        ],
        "interval": 1,
        "month": 8,
        "type": "relativeYearly"
    },
    "range": {
        "endDate": "2025-08-17",
        "startDate": "2021-08-17",
        "type": "endDate"
    }
},
"location": {
    "displayName": "Harry's Bar"
},
"attendees": [
    {
        "emailAddress": {
            "address": "chris@contoso.com",
            "name": "Chris Green"
        },
        "type": "required"
    }
]
```

}